# Get the rotation on Genuino 101

Tags: accelerometer

How can I get the exact rotation of the Genuino 101? I would like to create a plumb rule.

I tried the example app with processing, [Arduino/Genuino 101 CurieIMU Orientation Visualiser](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Genuino101CurieIMUOrientationVisualiser), but it didn't get the correct rotation. Sometimes the object on the screen has a different rotation from the board itself.